# How do I get R to Speak/Say The Current Time on MacOS?

Tags: r, datetime, time

I can get R to speak/say phrases using the `system` command.

For example:
`system("say What time is it?")`

How do I get it so say the current time?

One would think something like:
`system("say the current time is Sys.time()")`

would work but it does not.

Comment: does ``system("say the current time is `date +%I`")`` work?

Comment: @Waldi it says 'the current time is 09'

When I type in the date command: `date()`, the output is "Thu Mar 11 21:54:15 2021"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained [here](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20071226130633932), you could use the MacOS [date function](https://ss64.com/osx/date.html) :

```
system("say the current time is `date +%H:%M`")
```

Comment: This works!

Thanks!

Where can I read up on things like +%H and %M and what they mean?

Comment: Great! Thank you!